# PCBA failure - white "fluff"

Tags: failure, damage

I have a PCBA that seems to have failed due to poor wiring (no water damage). The screw terminals are for 230V AC input and electrical load relay.

What isn't clear to me is what exactly is the "white fluff" on the leg of the resistor. I believe it formed during the failure.

[image: Failed PCBA]

So the question would be - What is the white stuff on the leg of the resistor and how does an electrical failure cause it? Does it indicate some other issue with the component/board/process?

Thanks

Comment: metallic screw vapor deposition?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, could you please elaborate? Do you mean that the screw from the terminal vaporized and deposited on the leg of the resistor?

Comment: Take a sample of the white fluff and see if it will dissolve in a drop of water. If it doesn't, then it's likely plastic, fiberglass, etc.

Comment: Likely a metal Oxide insulator from arc flash vapor

Answer (score 0):

If it was present before the failure, it could be an excessive amount of flux from the soldering process, check if you see this on other solder connections or only in this one place.

We have also seen things like this from corrosion of component's lead material underneath the surface treatment of the lead (pin). Often times these are copper wires with a layer of tin around them. If components are extremely old before they are soldered, things similar to this can happen.

This could also be from the bare PCB manufacturing process rather than the component or the assembly. PCBs go through several electrochemical and cleaning processes. I remember a case from several years ago in which we had titanium salt deposits from an improperly controlled process at the manufacturers side.